# jQuery change and select

Tags: jquery, select

When I change select manually the `$("select").change` event triggers as expected. But it does not triggers if I change select via JavaScript

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72Lsw/

Why is this happens and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the value of the select via jQuery **won't invoke the event**:

```
$("select").val(rand_int);
```

You'll need to invoke it yourself, after setting it in jQuery, like so:

```
$("select").val(rand_int).change();
```

Comment: Thanks, got it! I thought it was a jQuery bug

Answer (score 2):

You will need to trigger the `change` event via code using:

```
$("select").val(rand_int);

// trigger change
$("select").trigger('change');
```